# Android Studio Gradle Sync Failed - Unsupported Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm on Linux (Arch Linux) and using Android Studio 2.3.1

When creating a new empty project in Android Studio I get the error:

```
Gradle sync failed: 
org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/gradle/api/JavaVersion;)V
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

It seems that there is something with the java version. I have openjdk-8 installed and also tried with Oracle JDK version 8 (also tried with version 7).

Things i've tried:

- Using installed gradle or gradle that comes with Android Studio
- Removing `~/.gradle` and `~/.android`.

Update:
If I enter the project directory and run `gradle build` i.e. using my installed gradle version it seem to build. However, being able to run gradle from Android Studio seem essential to even use Android Studio.

Comment: You can configure Gradle of Android Studio to use your installed one rather than the wrapper

Comment: Yes, I did that. Still UnsupportedJava exception.

Comment: I would think that using that setting would allow the IDE to build similarly to the terminal. Guess not

Comment: Please post all of your `build.gradle` files. Please post output of `java -version`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to Android Studio 2.3.2 and then this particular problem was solved.

I did not use the package from AUR (Arch User Repository) when upgrading, instead I used the Android Studio "Check for updates" and upgraded that way. I don't know if that matters.

Update: 
Happened again when upgrading to Android Studio 3.0.1 from AUR. Installing the official build from http://developer.android.com works though so it's some issue with the build in AUR for ArchLinux.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem AFAIK.

Firstly I had a version previous to 3.0.1 of Android, then I downloaded the Android zip package from the official website, then installed it and kept the same old preference files (or so). Then this problem appeared. What I did is uninstalling (thus deleted the android-studio folder in terms of Ubuntu) and installing it back again and it was solved.